# MySql's 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS' misbehaves when database has live connections

Tags: mysql, database, locking

We have some initialization code that makes sure that all the needed resources are in place,
i.e.: creates those resources (files, directories, databases, tables, etc.) if missing, and does nothing otherwise.

But, when a database is in use (i.e. exists and already has live connections), a new app
that goes through the initialization code waits forever.

The reason is that 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS' is kinda stupid: it tries to own the database, even though it exists and nothing should be done.

Is there a way to check whether a database already exists, that does not involve such a lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
    WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'MyDatabaseName'
) AS e
```

Returns 1 if database exists (and the user executing the query has the appropriate privileges to be able to see it, blah blah blah); 0 otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure? Have you a reproducible-bug test-case? If so, please report it as as a bug.

I certainly see no such behaviour as described.

Comment: Weird: the problem exists when I use the C APIs (from C++ code), but not in python (using MySQLdb).

Answer (score 0):

Just assume that it does. If it doesn't, your system is horribly broken. It will be caught by SQL errors when you try to execute queries.